# Как доказать именное происхождение инфинитива?

Tags: морфология, историческая-грамматика, инфинитив, индоевропеистика

В «Лингвистическом энциклопедическом словаре» о неопределенной форме глагола написано следующее: «Исторически инфинитив в индоевропейских языках представляет собой перешедшую в парадигму глагола форму имени со значением действия». Сохранились ли в русском языке какие-либо свидетельства именнóго происхождения инфинитива? Каковы они?

Материал для анализа как подсказка.

*Ехать туда было бы ошибкой и Поездка туда была бы ошибкой* ;

*Желание поехать туда возникло само собой и Мысль о поездке туда возникла сама собой* ;

Ему запретили ехать и Ему запретили поездки ;

*Он захотел поехать туда и Поездка на море стала наградой за победу в конкурсе* .

Answer (score 2):

Косвенно о «глагольной неполноценности» инфинитива в русском языке свидетельствует отсутствие у этой формы нормального набора глагольных признаков: инфинитив отражает лишь категории вида, (не)переходности и (не)возвратности; не имеет форм наклонения, времени и лица.

[Некоторые источники](http://koi.tspu.ru/koi_books/kurysheva2/ifi.htm) также полагают, что омонимы типа *пасть* 'челюсть' и *пасть* 'сблизиться с землей' указывают на именное происхождение инфинитива. Тем не менее не ясно, как именно эти омонимичные формы «доказывают» именное происхождение инфинитива.

Суть вашей подсказки, кажется, понятна, но все же контексты, когда инфинитив выступает в роли зависимого члена предложения, тоже едва ли указывают на именное происхождение обсуждаемой глагольной формы. Обратите внимание, что не все инфинитивы способны выступать в подобной функции: *Прекратите беречь воду!*, но **Прекратите мочь!*

Comment: Совершенно верно, речь идёт о синтаксической функции. Вот морфологические  омонимы  печь пироги - тёплая 
 печь действительно не являются доказательствами.Здесь существительные образовались от глагола. Слова с суфф. -ть вначале обозначали действия и явления, а потом в некоторых из них развилось предметное значение.

Comment: Но синтаксическая функция тоже никак не свидетельствует о происхождении инфинитива из имени, верно? ;) Насчет суффикса -ть не уверен, но это к делу не относится.

Comment: Ну, почему  же не свидетельствует, если инфинитив ведёт себя как существительное?

Comment: @Людмила а как вы предлагаете доказать, что это непременно связано с его происхождением от отглагольного имени в праславянский период? У супина и инфинитива действительно были специфические контексты (а супин, к тому же, в раннедр.-рус. период еще подавал признаки жизни и индицировался специальным маркером -тъ), но уже в ДРЯ истинно именными формами глагола были лишь причастия.

Comment: Ну, про супин я не собиралась спрашивать, это уже глубины науки, хотя приятно, что эта тема кому-то знакома. Остатками настоящего слав. супина в совр. р. языке являются формы неопр. накл. у глаголов с корнем на заднеяз. согласный - печь, лечь, мочь, стеречь, отвечающие старослав. супину пешть, лешть, могить, стрешть. И та, и другая формы восходят еще к праслав. образованиям под влиянием неопр. наклонения на -шти: пешти, лешти, мошти и т. д. Настоящий супин от корней пек-, лег- был бы *пек-т, *легт,  получились бы  формы * пет, * лет, в которых корень пек-, лег- не чувствовался бы совсем.

Comment: Я спрашиваю об остатках в совр. русском языке - а в совр. языке инфинитив ( а он в определ. момент вобрал в себя и супин) ведёт себя тоже как существительное, а иногда как прилагательное. В общем, видимо, кроме нас с Вами, это никому не интересно, пора давать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Об именном происхождении инфинитива (неопределенной формы глагола) свидетельствует его синтаксическое поведение. Форма инфинитива глагола (в отличие от всех других его форм) может выполнять в предложении любую синтаксическую функцию, в том числе и все те функции, которые свойственны именам существительным. Например,

*Ехать туда было бы ошибкой и Поездка туда была бы ошибкой (ехать и поездка — подлежащие)*;

*Желание поехать туда возникло само собой и Мысль о поездке туда возникла сама собой* (поехать и о поездке — определения);

*Ему запретили ехать и Ему запретили поездки* (ехать и поездки — дополнения);

*Он захотел поехать туда и Поездка на море стала наградой за победу в конкурсе* (поехать и наградой — основная смысловая часть сказуемого).

Есть и функция обстоятельства цели. При глаголах движения и выражающих отказ от перемещения или прекращения движения инфинитив является обстоятельством цели: *Мужик гнал гусей продавать и Мужик гнал гусей с целью продажи.*

Другим формам глагола это не свойственно.

Comment: А что дает основания полагать, что эта синтаксическая способность современного инфинитива исторически восходит к синтаксическому поведению инфинитива хотя бы в раннедревнерусский период (о праславянском состоянии даже не говорю)? Почему это не может быть поздней инновацией?

Comment: Так ведь мы не доказываем справедливость утверждения, что инфинитив - отымённое образование, это до нас доказали, об этом говорит приведённый Вами материал об истории инфинитива, мы же ведём речь о современных свидетельствах родства инфинитива и имени.

Comment: Людмила, во-первых, это, строго говоря, предположение, как и вся работа с реконструкциями — одна большая гипотеза. Доказано это... ну, это трудно назвать доказательством. От чего-то должен был образоваться этот инфинитив? Должен. От чего? От основы имен. А вот как он функционировал, в чем проявлялись его особенности, мы, кажется, мало что знаем. Во-вторых, вы ставите вопрос: «Как доказать именное происхождение инфинитива?» и приводите в ответе материал из СРЯ, связь которого [материала] с прасостоянием ничем не подкрепляется. В этом и загвоздка.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что взаимозаменяемость сущ. и инф. в СРЯ берет истоки в истории происхождения последнего и доказывает отыменное происхождение инфинитива? Я об этом спрашиваю.